# Why Static Shared Preferences are not saved?

Tags: android, static, sharedpreferences, static-methods

I want to access Shared preferences static way to avoid using excessive code, but when I read shared preference, looks like was not saved whith the static method "setSyncDBIsNeeded()", what I'm doing wrong?

MyApplication code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

My preferences activity:

```
public class PreferenceController {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static String project = "com.example.myproject";

    public PreferenceController() {
        sharedPreferences = MyApplication.getContext().getSharedPreferences(project, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public PreferenceController(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(project, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /* getters and setters */

    // Static methods

    public static void setSyncDBIsNeeded(boolean value) {
        Log.d("PREFCON","Setted DBSyncNeeded : "+value);
        getSharedPrefferences().edit().putBoolean("DBSyncNeeded", value);
    }

    public static boolean getSyncDBIsNeeded() {
        Log.d("PREFCON","DBSyncNeeded: "+getSharedPrefferences().getBoolean("DBSyncNeeded", false));
        return getSharedPrefferences().getBoolean("DBSyncNeeded", false);
    }

    private static SharedPreferences getSharedPrefferences() {
        return MyApplication.getContext().getSharedPreferences(project, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

Then in another class I do:

```
PreferenceController.setSyncDBIsNeeded(true);
PreferenceController.getSyncDBIsNeeded();
```

and its printed in Log:

```
07-14 14:24:04.665 27658-27658/com.example.myproject D/PREFCON: Setted DBSyncNeeded : true
07-14 14:24:04.665 27658-27658/com.example.myproject D/PREFCON: DBSyncNeeded: false
```

Comment: You forget to call `commit()` after setting the value. Try `getSharedPrefferences().edit().putBoolean("DBSyncNeeded", value).commit();`

Comment: calling "commit()" worked ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPrefferences().edit();
editor.putBoolean("DBSyncNeeded", value);
editor.commit();
```

You have to remember to update the changes made to the SharedPreferences, so SharedPreferences actually save it.

Inserted into your code:

```
public static void setSyncDBIsNeeded(boolean value) {
    Log.d("PREFCON","Setted DBSyncNeeded : "+value);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPrefferences().edit();
    editor.putBoolean("DBSyncNeeded", value);
    boolean completed = editor.commit();
    Log.e("PREFCON", "Updating SharedPreferences was " + completed + "!";
}
```

By adding a boolean value to be set to editor.commit you can easily know if it was a success or not. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) the commit() method returns a boolean value based on if it completed or not. True means the editing was successfull, while false means something went wrong.

Comment: Your efforts to extend the answer are appreciated, I didn't know this way to access to shared preferences :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`commit`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) or [`apply`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) to actually perform the request.

> Commit your preferences changes back from this `Editor` to the
>   `SharedPreferences` object it is editing. This atomically performs the
>   requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the
>   `SharedPreferences`.

```
public static void setSyncDBIsNeeded(boolean value) {
    Log.d("PREFCON","Setted DBSyncNeeded : "+value);
    getSharedPrefferences().edit().putBoolean("DBSyncNeeded", value).apply();
}
```